# Cordova Android plugin FileTransfer not returning a callback from native

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I have been trying to figure this out for the last three days and as of yet have not figured out a solution. I'm creating an app for android and iOS in which the iOS version works as it should but the android version is not downloading the content that I need it to in order to actually load the next next page.

The issue is that I make a call to download a zip using FileTransfer plugin v0.4.4  the javascript side works fine and I have done a step through on the native source and it's coming through but it is not returning a callback for either success, error or onprogress which means that the scripts that need to run in the callback never get fired. I've looked and the data folder that it's being saved to and the file is being downloaded it is just the callbacks that are not working.Whats even stranger is that sometimes it will work but if I reinstall the app it will 9/10 times start failing again.

I've tried reverting to v0.4.2 of the plugin which from research sometimes solved the issue but in my case it has not. Has anyone else encountered this problem at all? or as any idea how to fix it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you debug the FileTransfer.java file and see in which line it stops working?

Comment: i've tried but by all i can see it looks like its working it gets to the end of the script and runs the correct function just nothing happens

Comment: I have this issue too. Not just with this plugin... Have you found any solutions?

Comment: I found a work around for file reading by using cdv file to access files but it was not the ideal solution and downloading still dosent work properly, i had to split up the dowmload requests and then sequentially run through them all. I found the issue is only for android prior to 4.4 which used the old webview not chromium webview and i think it has something to do with callback getting overwritten or forgotten about in memory that will be harder to fix i'm afraid